# Unexpected result converting double to int

Tags: ios, objective-c, casting, int, double

I was trying to cast a `double` value to `int` and I got a different value.

I have this code:

```
double double100times = 240;
int a=[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:double100times] intValue];
```

and the value I get from this is `a=239`.

If I use `int a= (int)double100times` instead I get the same value.

Why is this?

UPDATE: If I use     double double100times = 240; works, 
but I'm using:

```
 double double100times = (2.3*100)+10;
```

Comment: Find the Wikipedia article on IEEE Floating Point and study it, especially the part where they explain that most values do not have an exact floating-point representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this code

```
double double100times = 240;
    int a=[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:double100times] intValue];
    NSLog(@"Integer : %d",a);
```

It results me

> Integer : 240

Are you sure, check  your log again..

EDIT :-

A workaround solution..

```
double double100times = ((2.3*100)+10);
    NSLog(@"Value : %f",double100times);
    int a=[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:double100times] intValue];
    int b = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",double100times] intValue];
    NSLog(@"Integer : %d",a);
    NSLog(@"Integer : %d",b);
```

Comment: If I do that I get the good value actually. The problem is when I get the value, my real code is this.


       double double100times = (2.3*100)+10;
       int intValue=[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:double100times] intValue];

and somehow is working when I write 240, but when I use (2.3*100)+10; instead is not working..